# How can I set the exit code from return code of my Execute File in Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, exit-code

I want to get return code (negative value) from my `{app}\{#MyAppExeName}` for setup exit code (MyAppExeName will run 20~30s)

I refer many example codes, and `Exec` can get result code 
but still don't know how to add to `[Code]` section for setup exit code (I have no idea about Pascal Script)

Below is `[Run]` section in my Inno Setup Script

```
[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

How to change `[Run]` & `[Code]` section for my goal?

Please help me and give me example code

Thanks

BR,
Alan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run an external process and retrieve its exit code, using [`Exec` support function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_exec).

To modify installer's exit code, implement [`GetCustomSetupExitCode` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=GetCustomSetupExitCode)

```pascal
[Code]

var
  ExitCode: Integer;
  
procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
  if CurStep = ssPostInstall then
  begin
    if Exec(
         ExpandConstant('{app}\{#MyAppExeName}'), '', '', SW_SHOW,
         ewWaitUntilTerminated, ExitCode) then
    begin
      Log(Format('Command finished, exit code is %d', [ExitCode]));
    end
      else
    begin
      Log('Failed to run command');
    end;
  end;
end;

function GetCustomSetupExitCode: Integer;
begin
  if ExitCode <> 0 then
  begin
    Log(Format('Returning exit code %d', [ExitCode]));
  end;
  Result := ExitCode;
end;
```

---

Note that Windows process exit code cannot be negative. The exit code is an unsigned 32-bit integer.

See how `uExitCode` parameter of [`ExitProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-exitprocess) and well as `lpExitCode` parameter of [`GetExitCodeProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getexitcodeprocess) are of `UINT` and `DWORD` types respectively.

It's just a common error/misconception that the exit code is interpreted as signed.

The Inno Setup follows that misconception by using signed integer value in `GetCustomSetupExitCode`.